# How to add a different data to multiple text files using python?

Tags: python, yolo

I am student and learning python. I am at a basic level. I am facing an issue to edit the contents of multiple text files. The text files that i have are the annotation files of some images. The images are of multiple shafts in a tray and the annotation files consist of the midpoints and a point along the length of the shaft i.e., (x0,y0) and (x1,y1). I need to insert the angle into these text files using the command math.atan2(y1-y0,x1-x0).

So can any of you guys help me and guide me

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to review [What can I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). In your case, you should try to solve the problem yourself, and come back if you have specific questions with your code rather than asking about the entire problem.

Answer (score 1):

When editing text files the solution is generally to overwrite the file while keeping all the data you want from it and adding the edits before you write to the file. Below is an example I run everyday.

```
    hour = str(dt.datetime.today().hour)
    output_file = Path(str(Path(__file__).parents[0]) + f"/{filename}.txt")
    new_lines = []
    with open(output_file , "r+") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            splice = line.find(":")
            if line[:splice] == hour:
                line = line.replace(line , f"{line[:-1]}{viewers} , ]")
            if int(line[:splice]) != 23:
                new_lines.append(f"{line}\n")
            else:
                new_lines.append(line)
    with open(output_file , "w+") as file:
        file.writelines(new_lines)
```